# Small near-reciprocals

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory

Let $p$ be large prime in $[T,2T]$ where $T$ is a parameter.

1. Can we have an integer pair $a,b$ satisfying $ab\equiv c\bmod p$ such that $|c|$ is of size $O(\operatorname{polylog}(T))$ and $a,b$ are of size $O(T^{1/2 +\varepsilon})$?
2. If $1/2$ is impossible what is the best rational in exponent we can get?
3. Given $p$ how many such minimal generically positioned pairs are possible?

Comment: A good person to ask would be Igor Shparlinski

Comment: It is believed that there are infinitely many primes of the form $n^2-2$. For such a prime, let $a=b=n$, $c'=2$. (Why $c'$, and not just $c$?) (Is $c'$ allowed to be negative?)

Comment: In particular, the following survey of Shparlinski has a lot of information about this sort of problem: https://arxiv.org/abs/1103.2879

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a nice article of Heath-Brown in the Mathematical Intelligencer, called Arithmetic applications of Kloosterman sums, where this problem is discussed under the heading, "An elementary problem."  He derives exponent $3/4$ and remarks that it is open to improve on it.  I am not aware of any subsequent improvements.

Comment: Is the 3/4 relevant here https://mathoverflow.net/questions/420905/simultaneous-small-near-reciprocals-at-two-distinct-primes?